# Android App emulator shows a blue bar at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am facing a strange issue when i execute my android application on the android emulator. A strange blue bar appears at the bottom of the screen. This cannot be related with application top bar.

Here is the screenshot:

[Blue Bottom Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dwUV.jpg)

How i am able to remove this bar from my app?

Thank you in advance for the help,

Lampros